# sapui5 sap.ui.unified.Calendar How to disable past dates

Tags: sapui5

Can someone help me how can i disable past dates using [sap.ui.unified.Calendar](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.unified.Calendar#overview).

[image]

In the above image if you see, March 8, 2021 was my current date. Now i have to disable all my past dates(Dates must be grey out and User should not be able to select the previous dates) from Current Date. Only user can select current date and future dates.

Below is the code im trying..

```
<u:Calendar id="calendar" select="handleCalendarSelect">
    <u:disabledDates>
        <u:DateRange startDate="{getDisabledDatesModel>/startDate}" endDate="{getDisabledDatesModel>/endDate}"/>
    </u:disabledDates>
</u:Calendar>
```

## Controller.js

```
var startDate = new Date("01-01-1900");
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(today);
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
today.toDateString();
var endDate = yesterday;
var disabledDatesModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
disabledDatesModel.setProperty("/startDate", startDate);
disabledDatesModel.setProperty("/endDate", endDate);
this.getView().setModel(disabledDatesModel, "disabledDatesModel");
```

In the xml file, im using `disabledDates` aggregation to fix the issue. But im not sure where im doing mistake.

Can some one please help me how can i fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is even [an example](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.unified.Calendar/sample/sap.ui.unified.sample.CalendarMinMax) to set the minDate for your calendar. In your solution users would be able to set every date before 1900.

Comment: @Marc, I agree that we have both minDate and maxDate, But for me disabling of Dates (dates must be grey out and user should not able to select the calendar) is required.. I tried with that too..im not sure how minDate and maxDate will help me

Comment: @user3496976 but greying out and disabling all dates before a minimum date is exactly what `minDate` does. Just set it to yesterday. You won't need the `disabledDates` aggregation